Div with horizontal scrollbar clipping content
the following html / css, which is a simplified version of my code clips the left side of the scrollable div when the width of the screen gets too narrow.
The horizontal scrollbar appears but you cannot scroll to the far left anymore.
Why does this happen?


.player {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 9rem;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.player-container {
    display: flex;
}
    <main style="width: 400px">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="player-container">
                <p class="player">Preston Hilton</p>
            </div>
            <div class="player-container">
                <p class="player">Peregrine Jewell</p>
                <p class="player">Waldo Symons</p>
            </div>
            <div class="player-container">
                <p class="player">Seymour Nicholson</p>
                <p class="player">Sheard Tyler</p>
                <p class="player">Thomas Post</p>
            </div>
            <div class="player-container">
                <p class="player">Landen Dean/p></p>
                <p class="player">Koda Abbott</p>
                <p class="player">Quentin Berry</p>
                <p class="player">Anson Dickinson</p>
            </div>
            <div class="player-container">
                <p class="player">Oscar Kelsey</p>
                <p class="player">-</p>
                <p class="player">-</p>
                <p class="player">-</p>
                <p class="player">-</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>




(Edited the Answer) Only if this works for you. See snippet below:
Just add this to .container class: flex-wrap: wrap;


.player {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 9rem;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-x: auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.player-container {
    display: flex; 
}
<main style="width: 400px">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="player-container">
                <p class="player">Preston Hilton</p>
            </div>
            <div class="player-container">
                <p class="player">Peregrine Jewell</p>
                <p class="player">Waldo Symons</p>
            </div>
            <div class="player-container">
                <p class="player">Seymour Nicholson</p>
                <p class="player">Sheard Tyler</p>
                <p class="player">Thomas Post</p>
            </div>
            <div class="player-container">
                <p class="player">Landen Dean/p></p>
                <p class="player">Koda Abbott</p>
                <p class="player">Quentin Berry</p>
                <p class="player">Anson Dickinson</p>
            </div>
            <div class="player-container">
                <p class="player">Oscar Kelsey</p>
                <p class="player">-</p>
                <p class="player">-</p>
                <p class="player">-</p>
                <p class="player">-</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>



Hope it helps!

Unfortunately if i add this it does not have a pyramid shape anymore.

Edited the answer. Just add this to .container class: flex-wrap: wrap;
